# What kind of pattern is this ('Provider')?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

At work we are using a 'pattern' that I didn't really find in the GoF book (but that may be due to lack of competence in this matter, I just skimmed the patterns) and that I'm still doubting somewhat.

Say, if we have a multi-project solution containing a project *DataAccess* that manages, well, the data access. Then usually I see it having a structure like this:

```
Providers (Folder)
 - DataAccessProvider.cs

Interfaces (Folder)
 - IFileLoader.cs

Implementors (Folder)
 - FileLoader.cs
```

Here, `FileLoader` would be an `internal` implementation of the interface `IFileLoader`, and the provider looks like this:

```
public static class DataAccessProvider
{
  public static IFileLoader FileLoader
  {
    get { return new FileLoader(); }
  }
}
```

What kind of design pattern is this (if any), and what are its real uses besides masking the specific implementation of the `IFileLoader` interface?

And secondly, is this really 'good style'? I wonder, for example, what happens if there are many calls like

```
string content = DataAccessProvider.FileLoader.LoadContentFromFile("abc.txt");
```

This would call `new FileLoader()` whenever it is used. Isn't there a more elegant way to do a similar approach?

Comment: looks a lot like a specialised service locator to me. And ServiceLocator is an antipattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this example the `DataAccessProvider` is an example of a simple Factory Method (pattern). Normally you would have a method called `GetFileLoader()` or `CreateFileLoader()` instead of a Property version, but the result is the same.

The purpose of returning the `IFileProvider` instead of `FileProvider` is for Dependency Inversion, this way one could write other types of `FileProvider` and inject them into the application without needed to rework or recompile all of the object that depend on an `IFileProvider`. It's not about masking.

If one is concerned about how many instances of `FileLoader` are created, then one could use the Singleton pattern for that object. However, this is normally not an issue if the `FileLoader` is a lightweight object, since the CLR garbage collector will take care of that automatically for you.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I wonder if that pattern is *always* useful though, since we are using it in nearly every single project inside the solution, and 90% of the time there is (and always will be) only one implementation of the respective interface. At this point the Provider class becomes a collection of methods to get implementations of different interfaces used for data access. Is it still good practice then if you know you will never swap out that implementation?

Comment: To be technical, nothing is always useful. That said, it is generally best practice to use an interface since it buys you a lot (helps with dependency inversion, unit testing, mocking, IoC containers and so forth). And if you are using an interface then it is simplest to use an IoC Container or Factories. The ability to swap out is useful, but not necessary for the value to be there.

Comment: If it's a very small or personal project, then it might not be worth the time and effort to follow those patterns.