# Provide different data access interfaces from a central class: is there a pattern I could/should use?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, data-access

I want to begin rewriting (step by step) a data access layer in an old application. We use the Entity Framework as object relational mapper, so the "pure data access" is already done. What still needs to be done is providing the "next" layer (I call it that because it's not clear right now if the old business layer is going to stay at all; this might lead to the question where the methods I'm talking about should go, layer-wise) with the necessary methods to get the data it needs.

Since there will be many methods needed, putting them all in one huge interface/class didn't seem the right way of doing it to me. I rather think of separating these "getting data" methods thematically. That is, something like this:

```
interface IBillDataAccess { .. }
interface IAttestationDataAccess { .. }
interface ICustomerDataAccess { .. }
```

and so on.

(1) Do you think it is useful here to use interfaces at all (I think so), even when the implementation of those is not likely going to change? I'd have to add new methods to both the interface and implementation.

(2) I would usually accumulate the creation of the concrete implementation of these interfaces inside a "provider" class, as I have seen in many of our smaller projects before. It usually looks like this ([similar old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354722/what-kind-of-pattern-is-this-provider), but now I have way more interfaces):

```
public static class DataAccessProvider
{
  public static ICustomerDataAccess GetCustomerDataAccess()
  {
    return new CustomerDataAccess();
  }

  public static IBillDataAccess GetBillDataAccess()
  {
    return new BillDataAccess();
  }
  // and so on
}
```

Something about this design is bothering me, though I cannot put my finger on it. I'm sure your opinions will help me out here!

Another point (intersects with (1)): I'm not yet sure if I like the `DataAccess` classes not being static. But having static classes for this would mean I can't use any interface.

I appreciate any input on this as I'm really quite insecure about all this, and unfortunately the people I'd usually ask are not here for the time being. Feel free to doubt and criticize anything I did in the above ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T:class
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetAll();
        T GetById(object id);
        void Insert(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);         
    }
```

you can use repository pattern and Unit of Work Patterns in here as well.

```
 public class Repository<T>:IRepository<T> where T:class
    {
        private DbContext context = null;
        private DbSet<T> dbSet = null;

        public Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        }

        #region IRepository

        public void Insert(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return dbSet;
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            this.context.SaveChanges();
        }

       #endregion
    }
```

More working example you can find in [Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: This looks very interesting, thanks! I have some further questions though: This would still logically "belong" to the data access layer, wouldn't it? And it would push me towards working with a long-running context, right? Or otherwise I'd have to create a new `Repository<T>` instance for every data access and wrap it in a using statement with a new context, which seems awkward to me. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: yes it's belong to data access layer and u can create generic repository. then you do not need to create instance for every data access. check the link and read the last part of the article `Implement a Generic Repository and a Unit of Work Class`

Comment: After I tried writing some test code with the above, I figured that I don't need this at all to write transaction-safe data access, and that it just feels like an unnecessary abstraction layer. Everything I tried doing with this pattern ended up being shorter and basically doing the same with just short-running contexts. After some more reading I then found [this blog post](http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/) which made very much sense to me!

Answer (score 1):

You are in search of [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) and for leveraging transactions use [Unit Of Work](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)